# Ordering nodes in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to get Graphviz to order nodes that share a common node, but not entirely the same path. In my example I have 5 leaf nodes, all connected to the same parent.

Not only are they out of order though, they also do not share the same pathways. Three leafs arrive via one route, the other two via a different one(I'm not sure whether that even matters)

I tried setting 'ordering=in/out' and similar but so far couldn't figure out how to do it. Help would be very much appreciated.

My example tree:

```
strict digraph "so example" {
    rankdir=LR;
    "0" -> "3" -> "4" -> "5" -> "C";
    "0" -> "3" -> "4" -> "5" -> "A";
    "0" -> "6" -> "7" -> "5" -> "E";
    "0" -> "6" -> "7" -> "5" -> "D";
    "0" -> "6" -> "7" -> "5" -> "B";
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to show A, B, C, D and E in order, top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering the nodes in the desired order should do the trick:

```
strict digraph "so example" {
    rankdir=LR;
    "0" -> "3" -> "4" -> "5" -> "A";
    "0" -> "3" -> "4" -> "5" -> "B";
    "0" -> "6" -> "7" -> "5" -> "C";
    "0" -> "6" -> "7" -> "5" -> "D";
    "0" -> "6" -> "7" -> "5" -> "E";
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
strict digraph "so example" {
    rankdir=LR;
    "0" -> "3" -> "4" -> "5" -> {A; B; C; D; E;}
    "0" -> "6" -> "7" -> "5";
}
```